# Why whole of Kinetic Energy is not lost in collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, collision

I have recently started studying about center of mass in high school and in the topic **collisions** the book has stated that:

> If an object of mass m moving with a velocity $u$ collides with an identical object of same mass at rest . Then the fractional loss in Kinetic energy is given by the equation :
> $$\frac{\Delta KE}{KE} = \frac{1-e^{2}}{2}$$
> where : e is the coefficient of restitution . KE = Initial Kinetic Energy and $\Delta KE$ is change in Kinetic Energy after the collision.

My question is that even if the collision is **perfectly inelastic** then why doesn't the energy lose go up more that 50%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One answer as to why it impossible to lose all of the kinetic energy in this situation has to do with conservation of momentum.

One object is specified to be at rest while the other is moving. This makes it impossible for the total momentum of the system of two objects to be zero.  For that you would need to have the two objects initially moving in opposite directions.

In any collision, elastic or inelastic, the total momentum is conserved.  If you start with non-zero momentum before the collision you must have non-zero momentum after the collisions.  That means something must be moving which means there must be non-zero kinetic energy.

Comment: thanks M. Enns for such a deep clarification

Answer (score 6):

Because momentum must be conserved.  A mass $m$ moving with velocity $v_i$ has a momentum $p=mv_i$ prior to the collision. If both objects were at a dead stop after the collision, then $p=0$, which does not conserve momentum.

In your example, where $e=0$ (totally inelastic), the final state is:

$$p=2 mv_f=2m\frac {v_i}{2}=mv_i$$

which conserves momentum. Since the mass has doubled, the velocity must be halved.

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt . One more question I have is what if the whole energy is transformed into some other form like sound or heat ?

Comment: It can't be.  The final product must always have some velocity consistent with the conserved momentum, meaning it will have kinetic energy. If a moving object hits a rigid wall, it can fully stop because the wall applies a force that changes the momentum (in accord with Newton 2nd law)

Comment: thanks for answering all my queries . Now I can finally focus in physics classes . 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

If a moving lump of clay smacks into an identical stationary lump of clay, they combine for form a bigger lump and that lump is moving. Since it is moving, it has kinetic energy. The final kinetic energy cannot be $0$.

If two identical lumps of clay are moving toward each other at the same speed, they combine to form a stationary bigger lump. In that case, there is no final motion and there is no final kinetic energy.